# JavaScript string modification (Probably involves regular expression)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The problem I need to solve is to shorten file paths given by the user. If you didn't know, sometimes it's not possible to enter in paths with spaces in the command prompt. You are required to either put the path in quotes or rename the paths with spaces to "abcdef~1".

Example: "C:\Some Folder\Some File.exe" should become "C:\SomeFo~1\SomeFi~1.exe" (case insensitive).

I'm making a function in JavaScript to attempt to shorten file paths using this idea.

```
function ShortenFilePath(FilePath){
    var Sections = FilePath.split("\\")
    for (Index = 0; Index < Sections.length; Index++){
        while (Sections[Index].length > 6 && Sections[Index].match(" ") && !Sections[Index].match("~1")){
            alert(Sections[Index])
            Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].replace(" ","")
            Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].substring(0,6)
            Sections[Index] = Sections[Index] + "~1"
            alert(Sections[Index])
        }
    }
    var FilePath = Sections.join("\\")
    alert(FilePath)
    return FilePath
}
```

The problem is, it will leave out the file extension and spit out "C:\SomeFo~1\SomeFi~1". I need help obtaining that file extension (probably through regular expression). If you feel that this function can be optimized, please do share your thoughts.

UPDATE: I believe the problem has been resolved.

UPDATE 2: There were some problems with the previous code, so I revised it a little.

UPDATE 3: Fresh new problem. Yikes. If the name of the file itself without the extension is under 7 letters, then it will turn up as "name.e~1.exe".

UPDATE 4: I think I've finally fixed the problem. I THINK.

```
function ShortenFilePath(FilePath){
    var Sections = FilePath.split("\\")
    Sections[Sections.length - 1] = Sections[Sections.length - 1].substring(0,Sections[Sections.length - 1].lastIndexOf("."))
    for (Index = 0; Index < Sections.length; Index++){
        while (Index > 0 && Sections[Index].match(" ") && !Sections[Index].match("~1")){
            Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].replace(/ /gm,"")
            Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].substring(0,6) + "~1"
        }
    }
    return Sections.join("\\") + FilePath.substring(FilePath.lastIndexOf("."))
}
```

Comment: How do you know the short file name of: `longfilename.txt` is: `LONGFI~1.TXT`? It might also very likely be: `LONGFI~2.TXT` or: `LONGFI~3.TXT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this to get the extension:

```
someString.substring(someString.lastIndexOf("."))
```

you also asked for some code review, so:

1 - Your JS conventions are a little off, it looks more like C# :) Why the capital letter in variable and method names?

2 - You said you can go with the quotes option instead of using ~1, seems easier, why did you decide not to?

3 - Why do you need something like this in your JS?

Comment: 1. I haven't played around with JavaScript a lot. I'm doing most of my scripting in RBX.Lua (ROBLOX Lua). I capitalize everything because my OCD directs me to. :P

2. The quotes option has conflicts with my other scripts.

3. I'm making a webpage for myself to run some stuff on computers that blocks pretty much everything. No, I'm not hacking anything. I just want to be able to run Minecraft.

Comment: 1. Can't argue with that! 2. Can't you fix it with a simple escaping?

Comment: I've tried using \x22 and \" to escape, but they always end up with something wrong. By the way, your method worked beautifully.

Comment: Ok if you're having trouble with your current method you posted and still want the quotes solution, we can try help you with the escaping problem :) good luck!

Comment: Okay, there's a new problem now. Probably the final one too. If the name of the file itself is 6 letters or shorter, it will end up being something like "name.e~1.exe".

Comment: Your while does this check "Sections[Index].length > 6", did you add the extension before this check and not after?

Comment: I need to remove the extension from the last part of the array. It's something like this: Sections[Sections.length - 1] = Sections[Sections.length - 1] .... but I don't know the rest because it involves regular expression. :|

Comment: Not sure how you ended up needing to remove the extension, but use this: someString.substring(0, someString.lastIndexOf("."))

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function ShortenFilePath(FilePath){
    var Sections = FilePath.split("\\")
    var suffix = FilePath.match(/(\..*$)/)
    for (Index = 0; Index < Sections.length; Index++){
        while (Sections[Index].length > 6 && Sections[Index].match(" ") && !Sections[Index].match("~1")){
            alert(Sections[Index])
            Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].replace(" ","")
            Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].substring(0,6)
            Sections[Index] = Sections[Index] + "~1"
            alert(Sections[Index])
        }
    }
    var FilePath = Sections.join("\\") + (suffix? suffix[1] : '')
    alert(FilePath)
    return FilePath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.prototype.replace` with a callback:

```
function ShortenFilePath(FilePath){
    return FilePath.replace(/([^:\\]+)([\\|\.[^\\]+)/g, function(text,match1, match2){
        return match1.length > 8 ? match1.replace(' ', '').substr(0, 6) + '~1' + match2 : match1.replace(' ', '') + match2;
    });    
}
```

I am not 100% sure that this will output excactly what you need but probably you get the idea :)
<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tmyhe/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Fix for Update #3 problem:

```
if (FilePath.lastIndexOf(".") > 6){
   Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].substring(0,6) + "~1"
} else {
   Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].substring(0, FilePath.lastIndexOf(".")) + "~1"
}
```

And btw, this:

```
while (Sections[Index].match(" ")){
   Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].replace(" ","")
}
```

Should probably look like this:

```
Sections[Index] = Sections[Index].replace(/ /gm, "");
```

Comment: I used your second suggestion, but I think I've fixed the main problem. Thanks for your help.